# Maven Project : Pomeclip.xml errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to execute the following project from GitHub:

https://github.com/natzei/jvrp

I'm trying to install Install on a local repository.

I create a maven project on Eclipse IDE.

In my pom.xml field I put the following code :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>it.unica.informatica.ro</groupId>
  <artifactId>jvrp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <group-id>it.unica.informatica.ro</group-id>
        <artifact-id>jvrp</artifact-id>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

But I'm getting the followings errors:

[image]

Are these the steps I need to take? If you have an idea please help

Comment: It is called `groupId`, not `group-id`, similar for `artifactId`.

Comment: Jvrp is not in the Maven Central repository. So first, you have to build it with Maven `clean install` to get it in your local Maven repository and to be able to use it as dependency in your project. Did you do that? J Fabian Meier is right, in the [Jvrp's `README.md` the  Maven dependency snippet is incorrect](https://github.com/natzei/jvrp/pull/5/files).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't know enough about how to use Maven please can you write me the steps from a to z to run this project on my Eclipse IDE.

Comment: 1. Clone Jvrp 2. Import Jvrp 3. Right-click `Jvrp/pom.xml` and choose _Run As > Maven Install_. Finally, in your project, correct the syntax of the dependency.

Comment: I should clone jvrp in the command line ? and import it on Eclipse ?

Comment: I did the step from 1 to 3, Now I should create a maven project on eclipse and add the dependencies on the pom.xml file?

Comment: You can do it on the command line, but it's easier in Eclipse and it doesn't require Maven to be installed. Just drop the [GitHub website](https://github.com/natzei/jvrp) on your Eclipse which opens the prefilled _Clone_ dialog with the option _Import all existing Eclipse projects after clone finishes_ on the third page.

Comment: I did all this, but I'm stuck, I don't know where to put my code and in which pom.xml file I should put the dependencies

Comment: Create a new project via _File > New > Project...: Maven > Maven Project_ with the option _Create a simple project_. Add the dependency to your `pom.xml` as you did, but with correct syntax and for the Java version add `<properties><maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source><maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target></properties>` before the `<dependencies>` element. Then you should be ready to code.